# Flex 4.6 - Enable onClick (click) on an s:List or s:ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, onclick

I have been searching thru the posts but I have not been able to find (I could have missed it) how to allow items in an s:List or s:Arraycollection to be clicked to advance to another view in an mobile app. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
           >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private var _listDataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(['one', 'two', 'three']);

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                list.dataProvider = _listDataProvider;
                list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onListItemClick);
            }

            private function onListItemClick(event:Event):void
            {
                Alert.show('Replace this Alert with code to go to view ' + event.currentTarget.selectedItem.toString() + '.', 'Item #' + (event.currentTarget.selectedIndex + 1).toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:List id="list" 
            horizontalCenter="0"
            verticalCenter="0"
            />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I am new to this whole thing so im coming across another issue. Once i add that to my project I am now getting: 1120 - Access of undefined property Alert. and 1172 - Definitin mx.controls:Alert could not be found.  For the first issue i guess i need to add some other code?? and for the 1172 i changed the item you noted to change (Article) and im getting that...This may be easy stuff but as i stated I'm new so im getting errors. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your need to add `import mx.controls.Alert;` to your code. If you're using Flash builder, pressing CTRL+SPACE will trigger code completion, & if you type (anywhere in your script block or class) `alert` or even `aler` and pressed CTRL+SPACE, then ENTER, Flash Builder will add the import statement to your code for you, but if you simply paste something like `Alert.show('hello world')` the auto-import isn't triggered. In this case you can just delete the `Alert` entirely and replace it with whatever code you want to put inside the `onListItemClick` function.

Comment: Thanks again, as before i am still getting the issues. I'm not sure what im missing. Can you suggest a link to documentation or video or something...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue. For some reasons, flash builder is importing the Alert class correctly (import mx.controls.Alert) with its full package name but the project does not compile because it says "Import alert could not be found". I am developing a mobile application using SDK 4.6 which i know doesn't have support for mx controls. This only explains why mx namespace control classes aren't importing properly. I hope this answers your question correctly as i'd advice you to find other means of alerting information to the user. Maybe write a custom alert component or use the platform's alert control via Native extensions.